# Why does the movie Inside Man start with a Bollywood track?

Tags: analysis, soundtrack, inside-man

Why does the movie [*Inside Man*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454848/) have the Bollywood song [Chhaiya Chhaiya](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQmrmVs10X8) in its opening scene?

Comment: I was watching the movie on a computer and thought the music is coming from another tab in the browser. lol, then realized it is from the movie itself. Just curiosity I paused the movie and googled 'why' and reached here to get the answer. :) Enjoying the movie with the song!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the director's commentary on the DVD, Spike Lee addresses this. Short version; he liked the song so he used it.

When he was teaching film school, a student recommended the film *Dil Se..*, where the song is originally from. He simply really liked the song, and decided that he wanted to try to use it in a movie at some point.

The specific orchestral arrangement of the song was made specifically for *Inside Man*.

Comment: And yes, I did watch the movie for the first time, and checked out the commentary at the beginning, just to answer this question.

Comment: What you say is a version that the director wants you to believe. To me, it's a marketing stunt; after all, India is the biggest market for American films outside of America.